# Why does my IdentityServer4 discovery document lack formatting?

Tags: identityserver4

When I use the IdentityServer4 Sample programs and navigate to

```
http://localhost:5000/.well-known/openid-configuration
```

The page shows json without formatting.

I am expecting it to be formatted [as per the bottom of this page](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/quickstarts/1_client_credentials.html)

[image]
How do I fix it ?

Comment: Why does it need to be formatted?  And how would you like it formatted?

Comment: The JSON Formatters are browser plugins, and this has nothing to do with Identity Server

Comment: Thanks @m3n7alsnak3 that is the answer. Care to write it up?
I installed the pretty json formatter in Chrome.

Comment: Sure, I wrapped up something, with some examples :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The JSON Formatters are a browser plugins. The `discovery document` of Identity Server (and every other JSON result page) are coming as a RAW Json. You need some formatter and it will beautify the page for you.

Here are some, for some of the browsers (on which I can test and confirm):

- Chrome - [JSON Formatter](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/json-formatter/bcjindcccaagfpapjjmafapmmgkkhgoa?hl=en) (I personally use this one)
- Firefox - [Basic JSON Formatter](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/basic-json-formatter/)

Also [JSONView](https://jsonview.com/) has versions for both of the browsers.

Sorry I don't have Safari to try and confirm something on it, but I'm pretty sure that there are a lot of plugins.